# How to say “let's” in Portuguese?

Tags: tradução, tradução-inglês, expressões-equivalentes

I had the [same question in Spanish SE](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18226/13791) and since I've heard that Spanish and Portuguese are closely related sister languages but they may differ in details

- [Sister language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sister_language)
- [Comparison of Portuguese and Spanish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Portuguese_and_Spanish)
- [The differences between Spanish and Portuguese](https://www.reginacoeli.com/blog/the-differences-between-spanish-and-portuguese.html)

I decided to ask it here, too. Then:

I wanna translate the following into Portuguese.

> **Let's** make a website for remote sensing and photogrammetry real. **Let's** all press "commit" button!

I've been searching around for a while but seems that there is no equivalent for `let's` in Portuguese.
Some special cases like `let's go`, `let's make it happen`, `let's make love` have been asked on other forums but seems there is no special grammar like in English?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer for the question is: **"Vamos"**

> english == Let's make a website for remote sensing and photogrammetry real. Let's all press "commit" button!
>
> Portuguese == **Vamos** fazer um site de sensoriamento e fotogrametria remota. Todo mundo apertando o botão "Commit"!
>
> let's go == **Vamos** lá
>
> let's make it happen == **Vamos** fazer com que aconteça
>
> let's make love == **Vamos** fazer amor

Comment: this is absolutely it!  Something additional to note with vamos is that, if the context is clear, you can use "vamos!" on its own.  I often notice my brazilian friends say "let's!" on it's own instead of "let's go" or "let's eat" for example, because you can do that in Portuguese.  I suppose the closest example in English would be "shall we?", but that sounds very stilted.

Comment: other note.  In spoken portuguese brazilians seem to drop the final S of vamos a lot, and say "vamo"

Comment: @Some_Guy, "Vamos" is used by itself in some phrases because it is actually the verb "ir" (to go) and we don't have a word that is simmilar to "let's" (by itself)..... It is like if brazillians said "let's go do that" instead of "let's do that"

Answer (score 6):

Like [in Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18229), in European Portuguese we say «vamos» to the meaning of «let's»

> Vamos fazer um website... Vamos todos clicar em "commit"

And the other examples:

> vamos lá!
>
> vamos fazer com que aconteça!
>
> vamos fazer amor!

Comment: But in fact [finally guifa's answer earned more votes and it was also recommended by Carlos to accept guifa's answer as the accepted one in one of his comments](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18227/13791), the final accepted translation was `Hagamos real un sitio web para teledetección y fotogrametría. ¡pulsemos todos el botón “commit”!`? in fact `vamos` was just suggested as an alternative there. so can `façamos` be a better equivalent for `let's make` or not?

Comment: and seems that your answer is also true for Brazilian Portuguese according to Sidney's answer who is from Brazil. Thanks a lot

Comment: @sepideh yes, you could use "façamos" instead of "vamos fazer", but it sounds a bit more formal.

Answer (score 5):

### Literal or literate translation

*Let's go*, for example, [it is a contraction](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/let's) for *let us go*.
In this sense the literal translation in Portuguese is simply:

- *Deixemo-nos ir*

Though, no-one would say that in the daily life, but that is strictly the exact translation.

Therefore the literate translations for

> let's go
>
> let's make it happen
>
> let's make love

might be, considering you can use the imperative tense in the second person of the plural form (the one that corresponds to **we**):

> deixemo-nos ir
>
> deixemos que aconteça
>
> façamos amor

### Simple translation

As other have said, the common translation for *let's go* might be simply:

- *Vamos*
- *Vamos lá*
- *Bora lá* (slang)

[Pay attention](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/Conjugar/ir) that this verb tense *vamos* is not conjugated in the simple present form, but in the imperative form.

Hence the simple translations for those three expressions might be:

> vamos
>
> vamos fazê-lo
>
> vamos fazer amor

Comment: Essa ideia de fazer a tradução literal foi muito boa, para dar uma ideia de onde vem a expressão.

Answer (score 2):

As the other guys said, basically "vamos" is the equivalent to "Let's", i'd just like to add that, for the "commit" (in the IT context), there's an portuguese non-official verb which is "commitar", so you can say, vamos todos commitar (do commit).

Comment: But only on Brazilian Portuguese, in Portugal we say «vamos fazer *commit*».

Comment: Good catch, @JorgeB. we also use that expression sometimes in Brazil!